# Update (pull) all docker images at once

Tags: linux, docker

Is there a command to update (pull) all the downloaded Docker images at once in the terminal ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no built-in command to `pull` all `docker images` **at once**.

But you can try this (multiline) bash using docker [`--format`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output) :

```
for image in $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | grep -v '<none>')
do
  docker pull $image
done
```

Or in one line:

```
for image in $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | grep -v '<none>'); do docker pull $image; done;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this :

```sh
docker images | awk '{print $1":"$2}' | grep -v REPOSITORY | xargs -L1 docker pull
```

Answer (score 2):

The most "dockerist" way to do it is:

```bash
docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | xargs -L1 docker pull
```

Comment: While docker image names and tags may not contain blanks, which `xargs` would then use to split it into multiple arguments, it might still be a good idea to explicit set the line separator `\n` as the only valid character used for splitting: `-d '\n'`
And while we are at it, also a `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` to not run any command when currently no local image exists.
And `<none>` should be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pmhahn

Think that `xargs -d` is not available in all *nix systems like [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?xargs).

I will keep the answer without your suggestions to have a closer answer to most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep v1.0-code_latest docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 docker pull
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.